# Pulling information about a Tweet using a Tweet ID and the Tweepy API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, attributeerror

I am trying to create a list of Tweet IDs from my timeline and then pull information about each Tweet ID, like the username. I am eventually trying to retweet the most "popular" Tweet from my timeline, which I have logic to calculate elsewhere.

This first portion of the code works and creates a list of the Tweet IDs from Tweets on my timeline that are between 12 and 36 hours old. I need to do this because the logic I have for calculating the most popular Tweet is dependent on the number of likes and retweets, so if I did them over the last 12 hours it would be biased towards the older Tweets.

```
def create_list(tweet_list):
     for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items():
         tweet_date = tweet.created_at 
         tweet_age_seconds = tweet_date.timestamp()
         tweet_age_hours = tweet_age_seconds / 3600
         if (current_time_hours - tweet_age_hours) > 12 and (current_time_hours - tweet_age_hours) < 36:
             tweet_list.append(tweet.id)
     return tweet_list
```

Then I am trying to iterate through this list of Tweet IDs to pull information about each Tweet, like the user name. I am trying to do that with the following, but keep getting a `'ResultSet' object has not attribute 'user.id'` error.

```
for i in enumerate(tweet_list):
    status = api.statuses_lookup(i)
    print(str(status.user.id))
```

This causes an attribute error. How do I select which status to pull from the `api.statuses_lookup()` call? I am ultimately trying to pull the `user.id` for each Tweet in the list, so I can then see how many followers that user has.

Answer (score 0):

[`API.statuses_lookup`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.10.0/api.html#API.statuses_lookup) returns a `ResultSet` of `Status` objects. You can use it as a list of `Status` objects.

This is because `API.statuses_lookup` uses the [GET statuses/lookup](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-lookup) endpoint, which accepts up to 100 distinct IDs for the `id` parameter. You can optimize your code to pass up to 100 per request rather than one at a time. Otherwise, if you want to get a single Tweet, you can use [`API.get_status`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.10.0/api.html#API.get_status), which uses the [GET statuses/show/:id](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-show-id) endpoint.

However, for your purposes, you shouldn't need to use either. When you loop through the Tweets in the home timeline within `create_list`, you already have the `Status` objects. Each `Status`/[Tweet object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet) has a `user` attribute that is a [`User` object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet), which has `id`, `name`, and `followers_count` attributes.